# How to freeze columns in GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, gridview, css-position

I have searched many methods and solutions on the Internet, but none of them are applicable to my project. Can anyone please help to see if there is a solution，Below is my code

```
 <table class="NormalTable" id="tblResult" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="saveScrollPos" type="hidden" name="saveScrollPos" runat="server">
                    <%--update by tarlor 2020-7-1 WIDTH:955px to 41% and  HEIGHT:575px to 630px--%>

                    <div style="behavior: url(component/ScrollPos.htc); overflow: auto; width: 41%; height: 630px" scrollpos="<%= saveScrollPos.Value %>" persistid="<%= saveScrollPos.UniqueID %>">

                        <asp:GridView ID="gvVoue" runat="server" CssClass="NormalDatagrid" Width="4570px" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" OnRowDataBound="gvVoue_RowDataBound"
                            OnPageIndexChanging="gvVoue_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="gvVoue_Sorting" OnItemCreated="gvVoue_ItemCreated" PageSize="<%# inConstant.SapRecPerPage_VOUE %>"
                            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="NormalRowBg2"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                            <RowStyle CssClass="NormalRowBg1"></RowStyle>
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="NormalColHead" Height="16px"></HeaderStyle>
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="LockNormalRowPager"></PagerStyle>

                            <Columns>

                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="30px" CssClass="DgLockedCol"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# inGlobal.HtmlEncode((string) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ROW_NUM")) %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol" Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnView" ImageUrl="Images\view2.gif" CommandName="Details" ToolTip="View Details" CommandArgument='<%#(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COMP_CODE")+","+(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ACCT_DOC_NO")+","+(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FISCAL_YR") %>' OnClick="gvVoue_ViewDetails"></asp:ImageButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol" Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        &nbsp;
                                            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnViewImage" ImageUrl="Images\spacer.gif" CommandName="Image" ToolTip="View Image" CommandArgument='' OnClick="gvVoue_ViewImage"></asp:ImageButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <zz:zzSortButton ID="btnCompCode" runat="server" CommandName="<%#DataGrid.SortCommandName%>" CommandArgument="COMP_CODE" CssClass="DGColHeadLinkButton" DefaultSort="False">Comp. Code*</zz:zzSortButton>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# inGlobal.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COMP_CODE"))%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="80px" CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <zz:zzSortButton ID="btnDocNo" runat="server" CommandName="<%#DataGrid.SortCommandName%>" CommandArgument="ACCT_DOC_NO" CssClass="DGColHeadLinkButton" DefaultSort="False">Doc. No.*</zz:zzSortButton>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# inGlobal.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ACCT_DOC_NO"))%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="90px" CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DgLockedCol" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <zz:zzSortButton ID="btnFiscalYr" runat="server" CommandName="<%#DataGrid.SortCommandName%>" CommandArgument="FISCAL_YR" CssClass="DGColHeadLinkButton" DefaultSort="False">Fiscal Year*</zz:zzSortButton>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# inGlobal.HtmlEncode((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FISCAL_YR"))%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Below is my css code

```
.DgLockedCol {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: grey 1px solid;
    border-left: grey 1px solid;
    border-right: grey 1px solid;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This solution can be used normally on the IE browser, but the upgrade to Edge or Chrome cannot show the effect，Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is a freezed column?

Comment: Check this out: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/two_columns.html